# YouTube API without Credentials

Tags: ios, youtube-api

Is it possible to make a youtube app access the videos on a channel that isn't actually my channel? So i don't have the login details for the channel and I can't get any credentials apart from the public URLs?

Comment: You need to register your app and get your API key and you can access any channel that are featured on youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You'll want to use the following endpoints.

If you know the channel ID, do a GET request to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id={CHANNEL_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Alternatively, if you know the display name, do a GET request to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername={DISPLAY_NAME}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

In either case, you won't need oAuth credentials but will need to provide your read-only API key that you obtain from the developer's console (don't forget to turn on the YouTube DATA API).

Once you've made one of those two calls, you'll get back a JSON packet. In that packet, look at the `items` attribute -- it'll have all associated channels with the ID or display name. Loop over the items, and for each one you can access `contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads` to get the ID of that channel's uploads feed.

With the uploads feed ID, you make one final GET request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId={UPLOADS_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You'll get back the channel's videos in the response JSON packet's `items` attribute. Note that the call to the playlistItems endpoint can include the maxResults parameter, use pageTokens for pagination (when there are more results than your call is returning), etc.